# JavaScript Circumference, Diameter and Radius of Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to create a JavaScript program that will prompt the user to enter a range of numbers '3-6' for example and then output the area, radius and circumference of each number in the range.

Below is my code so far, I am aware it isn't working currently but a few pointers would be great!

```
function circum() {
var radius = prompt("Enter the a range of numbers for the circle","");
var radiusanswer = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
var area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
var cube = radius * radius * radius
alert("The circumference is "+radiusanswer)
alert("The area is "+area)
alert("The cube is "+cube)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Just need to loop properly for all numbers in range like below

```js
function circum() {
  var values = prompt("Enter the a range of numbers for the circle", "");
  var range = values.split("-");
  //range[0] = start value
  //range[1] = end value
  for (var i = range[0]; i <= range[1]; i++) {
    var radius = i;

    var radiusanswer = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    var area = radius * radius * Math.PI;
    var cube = radius * radius * radius
    console.log("The circumference is " + radiusanswer)
    console.log("The area is " + area)
    console.log("The cube is " + cube)
  }

}
circum();
```

Comment: Hey thanks very much for helping. Once I enter the two numbers I am greeted by a blank screen, how do I output the console log on the page after I input the values?